# Writing in excel file with poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am getting a phone number from one excel file and write into another excel file using the following code

```
cellph = row.getCell(3);
Object phone = cellph.getNumericCellValue();
String strphone = phone.toString();
cellfour.setCellType(cellfour.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cellfour.setCellValue("0"+strphone);
```

It writes the phone number as 09.8546586. I want to write it as 098546586(without precision value). How to do that?

Comment: Are you sure that "strphone" doesn't contain precision ? Usually Excel eliminates preceding 0 if cell type is number. your output is little wired.

Comment: _cellph.getNumericCellValue();_ will return double(which is primitive type. how are you storing it in Object?

Comment: if the cell is a numeric cell `getStringCellValue()` will throw an exception

Comment: i used getStringCellValue() but it says numeric value cannot be get in string.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not applying a cell style with a suitable format string in it?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't with the write. Your problem is with the *read*, that's what's giving you the floating point number

From your code and description, it looks like your phone numbers are stored in Excel as number cells, with an integer format applied to it. That means that when you retrieve the cell, you'll get a `double` number, and a cell format that tells you how to format it like Excel does.

I think what you probably want to do is something more like:

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

cellph = row.getCell(3);
String strphone = "(none available)";

if (cellph.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
   // Number with a format
   strphone = "0" + formatter.formatCellValue(cellph);
}
if (cellph.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
   // String, eg they typed ' before the number
   strphone = "0" + cellph.getStringCellValue();
}
// For all other types, we'll show the none available message

cellfour.setCellType(cellfour.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cellfour.setCellValue(strphone);
```

Comment: Dear gagravarr.org,       Thank you very much. I got the output. Once again thank you very much.